# How to resize partitions when upgrading to 12.10?

Tags: partitioning

I have got Ubuntu 12.04 alongside Windows 7 on Dell Inspiron mini 160 GB. The size of Ubuntu is not sufficient now. Can I redraw partition size when upgrading to Ubuntu 12.10, as I find myself not able to understand GParted.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You can resize the partition in the installation process. You have to select **something else** option in the partitioning phase. But, This can be sometimes tricky and I recommend using Gparted in the Live session.

If you are referring to resizing the partition while doing upgrade (using update-manager), you cannot. You cannot resize, delete or otherwise change the partition while using it (the partition is mounted at `/`)

#### If you want to upgrade with update-manager

If you want resizing of the existing partition, and also do not want to do a fresh installation, You can use the Live session. ***Take note that, you must have free space after the Ubuntu partition or create free space***

1. Boot to a Live Ubuntu system.
2. Open gparted by typing "Gparted" in the dash
3. Select the next partition just after the Ubuntu, Select *resize* and move the slider from left to right to make some space just after the Ubuntu installation. Then click on *Apply* button. *This might take some times, so take precaution for power/battery down*.

   [image]
4. After you created free space, select the existing Ubuntu partition, then *right-click* → *Resize* and move the slider from the right end to fill all the gray free space area. Then click on *Apply* button.

   [image]
5. Now, exit the Live session, boot to your Ubuntu installation and perform upgrade from it.

This method might not work, if your Ubuntu is a primary partition and the partition immediately following is an extended/logical partition. *(This might be possible also, but I haven't tested it)*.

Comment: AFAICT, he is upgrading (probably using update-manager) and I don't think you can resize using that method. Please add instructions on how to resize using Gparted.

Answer (score 0):

In that case , upgrading wont help you, you need to make a fresh installation of ubuntu alongside your existing windows, and while installation, you need to specify partition.

I suggest have a look at gparted once again : http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/gparted.html